# Was the "Irish ghost video" staged? If so, how?

Tags: ghosts

This video shows stuff moving around in a kitchen independently and has been called a video of a "poltergeist". It has 12 million views and even CBS shared it suggesting it as possibly true, when of course it's very likely faked.

> INTERNET ROUNDUP: This "ghost" video going viral on Facebook is downright creepy. Do you think it's legit?
>
> A woman in Ireland says she captured footage of a poltergeist that apparently enjoys trashing her kitchen.

Now, I know that the video wouldn't prove the existence of ghosts even if genuine, but is it? Was it staged? If so how?

[image]

https://www.facebook.com/ashling.murphy3/videos/993333220696990/

Please do not speculate about ghosts or various techniques on how this could be done in theory.

Comment: The strings are supposedly visible (at to the end of this debunking video):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvfeRuq1YWk

Comment: To summarise the excessive comments I have just deleted: There is controversy over whether this question is answerable. There is controversy over the deletion of an upvoted answer because it was opinion-based. If you want to discuss this instance more, please take it to chat. If you want to object to a mod action or have policies changed by getting community consensus, please take it to Meta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [hngn.com](http://www.hngn.com/articles/133814/20150926/ashy-murphy-poltergeist-haunts-woman-ireland-house-takes-video-evidence.htm), The Irish Ghost Video has two versions:

1. [Video 1: Ye think he have problems I'm down in the middle of no where with this happening to me wtf](https://www.facebook.com/ashling.murphy3/videos/989623281067984/) (*Non-viral video: 1m views*,15 September)
2. [Video 2: Its getting way worse I defo have to move house](https://www.facebook.com/ashling.murphy3/videos/993333220696990/) (*Viral Video: 12m views*, 22 September)

In Video 2, there is a possibility that a  visible unknown line at the end of the video at 1:07, attached to a red bucket, [Irish Examiner Reported](http://www.irishexaminer.com/examviral/real-life/video-this-cork-womans-haunted-house-just-might-make-a-believer-out-of-you-355417.html).  These are three different frames: 
[image: red bucket]
[image]
[image]

[Entertainment.ie](http://entertainment.ie/wtf/Watch-Yeah-that-supposed-ghost-video-from-Cork-is-totally-fake/370792.htm) found also another wires in the video:

> [image]
>   Now. Here's how you can spot the wires pulling everything. If you open the video up on a laptop and put into fullscreen with the 1080p setting, you can CLEARLY see a wire pulling the red clothes bin towards the camera. The wire slackens slightly as whoever's standing behind the camera pulls it.
>
> It's absolutely clear as day when you spot it because the light catches the wire just as it moves. Skip to 1.00 and you'll see it. Look just below the countertop and you'll see it.

Moreover, [hngn.com](http://www.hngn.com/articles/133814/20150926/ashy-murphy-poltergeist-haunts-woman-ireland-house-takes-video-evidence.htm) indicated that the video might be fake:

> Many have pointed out evidence that suggests the videos are fake. One person notes that after the camera shifts focus, you can see the light stop moving in the window's reflection. Another notes the lucky coincidence that the camera always moves to where the poltergeist is, right when it acts. (Photo : Twitter Photo Section)

Moving on, [deathandtaxesmag.com](http://www.deathandtaxesmag.com/264515/woman-posts-video-showing-supposed-poltergeist-trashing-her-home/) said:

> There’s nothing in this video that can’t be explained by her living next to some train tracks or having some loosely assembled IKEA accessories, except for the bucket. The bucket that skids rapidly along the floor at the end of the video is certainly weird, but it has a shock element to it that’s suspicious and it flies straight towards the camerawoman.

And asked the following question:

> **Which scenario is more likely? That the rules of the natural universe as we know them have been upended and invisible spirits with supernatural powers roam the earth? Or that the uploader of the video had access to some fishing line or wire?**

As skeptics, we can see that we have tremendous [scientific evidence](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/) [gained](http://srikant.org/core/phy11sep.html) [over the years](http://www.alcyone.com/max/physics/laws/) for the [physical laws of nature.](http://www.csicop.org/si/show/laws_of_nature_a_skeptics_guide) Anyone claiming otherwise needs to provide extraordinary evidence.

Comment: What would be the extraordinary evidence? If you don't know because everything can be disproved don't say we need that. Otherwise, you are lying and your claims are worthless.

Comment: I do know. Provide scientific evidence contradicting the physical laws of nature then start talking.

Comment: you talk like we know all physical laws in the universe. There is a ton of evidence that contradicts other physical laws. It's called science, where the previous belief becomes obsolete because a new discovery disproves it.

Comment: "There is a ton of evidence that contradicts other physical laws." Like what? And science is not a belief.

Comment: Science is a belief = https://www.quora.com/Is-science-a-belief-system. As for contradiction i.e according to the Theory of relativity, the distribution of galaxies should be homogeneous but that's not what is observed. See the axis of evil suggesting special direction. https://www.space.com/37334-earth-ordinary-cosmological-axis-evil.html